# Selenium RemoteWebDriver on Docker not working

Tags: selenium, spring-boot, docker

I install Selenium Hub and Chrome image on Docker. I installed and commissioned according to the instructions from Github Selenium. 
When I run the code below (it works on Spring Boot) it can be said that it crashes. There are no errors or warnings in the logs. When I entered control printlns it displays only "Part 1"; the rest of parts does not printing. So it's probably RemoteWebDriver trying to connect, but it's not working. How do you try to fix it?

(I'm sorry if I explained it poorly, but this is my first time dealing with Selenium and Docker and I'm just learning.)

Code:

```
 public void createChromeScreenshot() throws IOException {

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

        System.out.println("Part 1"); //it`s display in Spring Console

     RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);
        System.out.println("Part 2"); //not working
        remoteWebDriver.get("http://www.google.com);
        System.out.println("Part 3"); //not working
        File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)remoteWebDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        System.out.println("Part 4"); //not working

        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\tests.png"));
        remoteWebDriver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is your setup when it comes to docker containers? If the code you posted runs in a container then most definitely the url `127.0.0.1` is not correct. On the machine where it runs you need to make sure that you get a response on port 4444 (using curl or similar)

Comment: @Mihai When I enter 127. 0. 0. 1:4444/wd/hub in my browser, I get JSON with a NullPointExeption error (which I read is correct because I didn't submit anything). I also have a console at the address: 127. 0. 0. 0. 1:4444/grid/console . I don't know if it's important, but Spring application is not placed in a container. It's run locally.

Comment: **Problem solved:** Probably went wrong configuration /strukture with the Docker. After 3 times resetting the Docker, the application connects with Selenium and works properly.

Comment: That's good. I also couldn't think of anything wrong with your setup